# insertItemsAt collection view crashes

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am building an app that uses a collectionView to display recipes.  When the user scrolls to the bottom I call my server and fetch more recipes. Currently I call reloadData() after the server responds with new recipes.  This works, but it reloads everything when all I need to do is load the new recipes.  I've read similar posts indicating I can use insertItems - but for me this crashes with: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is my code:

```
func updateRecipes(recipesToAdd: Array<Recipe>) {
    let minNewRecipesIndex = (self.recipes.count + 1)
    recipes += recipesToAdd
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if recipesToAdd.count == self.recipes.count {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        } else {
            let numberOfItems: [Int] = Array(minNewRecipesIndex...self.recipes.count)
            self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: numberOfItems.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0) })
            // this crashes, but self.collectionView.reloadData() works
        }
    }
}
```

Even a simple hard coded - self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)) - crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- `minNewRecipesIndex` must be `self.recipes.count`. Imagine an empty array (`.count` == 0), the index to insert an item in an empty array is 0, not 1.
- `numberOfItems` must be `Array(minNewRecipesIndex...self.recipes.count - 1)` or `Array(minNewRecipesIndex..<self.recipes.count)`. Again imagine an empty array. Two items are inserted at indices 0 and 1, `minNewRecipesIndex` is 0 and `self.recipes.count` is 2, so you have to decrement the value or use the half open operator.

If the code still crashes use a `for` loop wrapped in `beginUpdates() / endUpdates()` and insert the items one by one at the last index.

Comment: Thank you! Argh, I thought testing with hardcoded indices ruled out the possibility that my indices were off.